# RecyclerView does not show last items whose picture is downloaded in background

Tags: android

I have a list which I use recyclerView to display. Each row in the list displays an image that is downloaded from a remote server. In order to speedup the display of the list I am downloading the images in the background. Each time the bind() wants to display the image I call a method that starts an asynchronous task that download the image and in the onPostExecute() method I call setImageBitmap() of the image to display the bit-mapped downloaded.

**The problem is as follows**

As I scroll down, the recyclerView loads more images that fits the screen and when the setImageBitmap() is called the list jumps up, so that the last 1 or 2 items in the list almost never displayed.

When I disable the call to setImageBitmap() there is no problem in displaying the last items (the list now is without images), and scrolling up and down the list.

The problem also shows up when I scroll down very slow. I limited the screen to show only 4 items, and as I scroll down to the 6th or 7th item suddenly the display jumps and displays again from item 2 to 5.

What is going on there and how can I make the display to scroll smoothly and without jumping all over?

Comment: have you tried picasso ?

Comment: No. I am not using it. I will look into it to find out how can it help me

Comment: Picasso fixed the problem. Thanks @Pankaj Nimgade

Answer (score 0):

There problem here comes to the fact your recycler view at the time it is inflated has size X, when you load your image the size changes but the `LayoutManager` is not aware of this change, hence it won't update your view.

You should post a snippet of your code, it will help to clarify.

Comment: Which part of the code should I post? the xml of the layout? of the row layout? the adapter code? the loading of the image?